# The sessions only store data for a second before being changed the last sessions value

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, session-variables

When I click the `Sort By Date Created` button, the string `date` is passed to the function `sort()` and alert 1 (see code) prints the string `date`. 
The string `date` is stored in the session in the first `if` statement and the alert 2 prints `date`. The issue is `date` is only being stored temporarily and alert 3 always alerts `service`, no matter the type. If I change the order of the if statements, the last if statement's string somehow always is stored in the session.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
  <script>

   function sort(type){

     alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['sort']; ?>');  ///ALERT 1

     if (type == 'date'){
       <?php $_SESSION['sort'] = 'date'; ?>
       alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['sort']; ?>'); ///ALERT 2
     }
     else if (type == 'cost'){
       <?php $_SESSION['sort'] = 'cost'; ?>
       alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['sort']; ?>');
     }
     else if (type == 'service'){
       <?php $_SESSION['sort'] = 'service'; ?>
       alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['sort']; ?>');
     }

     alert('<?php echo $_SESSION['sort']; ?>'); ///ALERT 3
  }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="sort('date');" value="Sort By Date Created">
  <input type="button" onclick="sort('cost');" value="Sort By Cost">
  <input type="button" onclick="sort('service');" value="Sort By Service">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about the difference between client side and server side code. You have essentially written the following code:

```
alert('service');
<?php
    $_SESSION['sort'] = 'date';
    $_SESSION['sort'] = 'cost';
    $_SESSION['sort'] = 'service';
?>
if (type == 'date'){

    alert('service'); ///ALERT 2
}
else if (type == 'cost'){

    alert('service');
}
else if (type == 'service'){

    alert('service');
}
```

PHP does not respect your javascript `if` statements. PHP will just compile into a static web page which is the latter part of the code I have written.

I feel an answer trying to explain the difference between the client-side and server-side code is a little broad and long-winded for StackOverflow, but there are plenty resources out there on that topic.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try passing data to another page using GET instead and storing it there :)